# Split a svg path d to array of objects

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there a way to split the `d` path string to an array of objects?

For example:

```js
const d = `M 0 0 L 0 10 C 0 10 20 30 20 20 Z`
const result = fromPathToArray(d)

// const result = [
//   { type: 'M', x: 0, y: 0 },
//   { type: 'L', x: 0, y: 10 },
//   { type: 'C', x1: 0, y1: 10, x2: 20, y2: 30, x3: 20, y3: 20 },
//   { type: 'Z' },
// ]
```

Here my starting code:

```js
const PATH_COMMANDS = {
  M: ["x", "y"],
  m: ["dx", "dy"],
  H: ["x"],
  h: ["dx"],
  V: ["y"],
  v: ["dy"],
  L: ["x", "y"],
  l: ["dx", "dy"],
  Z: [],
  C: ["x1", "y1", "x2", "y2", "x", "y"],
  c: ["dx1", "dy1", "dx2", "dy2", "dx", "dy"],
  S: ["x2", "y2", "x", "y"],
  s: ["dx2", "dy2", "dx", "dy"],
  Q: ["x1", "y1", "x", "y"],
  q: ["dx1", "dy1", "dx", "dy"],
  T: ["x", "y"],
  t: ["dx", "dy"],
  A: ["rx", "ry", "rotation", "large-arc", "sweep", "x", "y"],
  a: ["rx", "ry", "rotation", "large-arc", "sweep", "dx", "dy"]
};

export function splitPath(path) {
  const items = path.trim().split(/\s*,|\s+/);
  const segments = [];
  
  items.forEach((item, i) => {
    const type = isString(item) ? item : null
    // ...
  })

  return segments
}
```

Honeslty I don't know how to do..

Comment: Except that "a  4.12.12  001 4.13-1" is a perfectly valid arc command with 7 parameters since 001 counts as 3 parameters. You have to know each of those flag parameters is 1 character. Similarly you also have to know that 4.12.12 is actually parsed as 4.12, 0.12 and 4.12-1 is 4.12, -1

Comment: There are a number of [path data parsers](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords%3Asvg%20path%20parser) you could try. @RobertLongson `a 4.12.12 001 4.13-1` is not a valid arc command. `001` would be read as rotation=1. What you are alluding to is `a 4.12.12 0 014.13-1`.

Comment: Ahh, yes. Close but no cigar. You can also repeat all the parameters and they count as additional commands of that type (except M, m which becomes L, l). Not sure how you're going to store that.

Comment: Fabric JS already implements something like that, taking it as a string an returning a fabric object, which splits them up into array which you could, in turn, convert to point if you want to. I think you can find the relevant code here: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line4822 (warning this is a heavy page as it points at a HUGE source file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple routine for a case like the one you describe. Please, be aware that such a simple solution is only useful if you know the input follows a certain pattern. As shown in the comments, the general case is more complex. Also, you should add sanity checks to handle faulty input.

```js
const PATH_COMMANDS = {
  M: ["x", "y"],
  m: ["dx", "dy"],
  H: ["x"],
  h: ["dx"],
  V: ["y"],
  v: ["dy"],
  L: ["x", "y"],
  l: ["dx", "dy"],
  Z: [],
  C: ["x1", "y1", "x2", "y2", "x", "y"],
  c: ["dx1", "dy1", "dx2", "dy2", "dx", "dy"],
  S: ["x2", "y2", "x", "y"],
  s: ["dx2", "dy2", "dx", "dy"],
  Q: ["x1", "y1", "x", "y"],
  q: ["dx1", "dy1", "dx", "dy"],
  T: ["x", "y"],
  t: ["dx", "dy"],
  A: ["rx", "ry", "rotation", "large-arc", "sweep", "x", "y"],
  a: ["rx", "ry", "rotation", "large-arc", "sweep", "dx", "dy"]
};

function fromPathToArray(path) {
  const items = path.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '').
                replace(/-/g, ' -').
                replace(/(\d*\.)(\d+)(?=\.)/g, '$1$2 ').
                trim().
                split(/\s*,|\s+/);
  const segments = [];
  let currentCommand = '';
  let currentElement = {};
  while (items.length > 0){
    let it = items.shift();
    if (PATH_COMMANDS.hasOwnProperty(it)){
      currentCommand = it;
    }
    else{
      items.unshift(it);
    }
    currentElement = {type: currentCommand};
    PATH_COMMANDS[currentCommand].forEach((prop) => {
      it = items.shift();  // TODO sanity check
      currentElement[prop] = it;
    });
    if (currentCommand === 'M'){
      currentCommand = 'L';
    }
    else if (currentCommand === 'm'){
      currentCommand = 'l';
    }
    segments.push(currentElement);
  }
  return segments
}

const d = `M 0 0 10 10 L 0 10 C 0 10 
20 30 20 20 a 4.12.12 1 0 1 4.13-1 Z`;
const result = fromPathToArray(d);

console.log(result);
```