# Return which segment of a line is clicked on in an SVG with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, svg, graphics

I have an svg with a bunch of different paths.  An example of one looks as follows:

```
<path d="M2943648.169104896,472020.4539518825L2943637.730875478,472048.6771215173" />
```

I'm attempting to find a way to get which section of the line has been clicked.  I could add an onclick function which returns `d`, but this will only give me the full string as listed above, and I need just the relevant portion.  As in, if a user clicks the first part of the line it'll return the correct coordinates (`2943648.169104896,472020.4539518825`) or if they click on the second segment, it will show the other coordinates that are in the value for d. Some of these paths have many different line segments.

I found an answer on here with a deprecated method of doing this and I was wondering what the latest way to do this is.   Thank you.

Comment: `svg.onclick = event => document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY).id == 'someIDassignment';` You would have to expand on this or add a click trigger event for each one.

Comment: @quicVO that still returns the full `d` path. Not what part of the d path that the click pertains to

Comment: have multiple paths, one per segment. You could also iterate calling getPathSegAtLength and maybe getPointAtLength to figure out the nearest segment.

Comment: Can you post the link to the deprecated method? I am after something similar.. brute force method I have now is to split the d-path, draw invisible paths under the original path and use ``elementsFromPoint`` (note the plural!) to get one of those invisible paths. works create for Absolute pathdefinitions.. haven't made it to work with Relative yet.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman getPathSegAtLength is deprecated

Comment: Use the polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

- I took the path to Array segments code from another SO answer:
  [Split a svg path d to array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64945219/split-a-svg-path-d-to-array-of-objects)
- wrapped it in code that creates new d-paths, incrementally adding every segment
- replace the `mouseover` with a click
- remove the specific color for a path segment
- because N paths are overlayed some extra anti-aliasing kicks in

```html
<svg-path-extractor colors="orange,green,blue,gold,hotpink,red">
  <div id=label></div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M 0 0 C 15 2 3 18 7 21 A 1 1 0 0 0 14 6 L 0 10 C 0 10 20 30 20 20 q -2 -4 4.13 -1 Z"></path>
    <g id=segments></g>
  </svg>
</svg-path-extractor>
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-path-extractor", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let addPath = (d, stroke) => {}
      setTimeout(() => {
        let colors = this.getAttribute("colors").split `,`;
        let segments = [...this.querySelectorAll("svg path")].map(p => {
          return this.pathToArray(p);
        }).flat().map(seg => Object.keys(seg).map(key => seg[key]).join ` `);
        segments.map((seg, idx, arr) => {
          let d = arr.slice(0, idx + 1).join(" ");
          let p = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
          p.setAttribute("d", d);
          p.setAttribute("fill", "none");
          p.setAttribute("stroke", colors.shift());
          p.onmouseover = (evt) => {
          let label = `${idx}d=${d}`.replace(seg,`<b>${seg}</b>`);
            this.querySelector("#label").innerHTML = label;
          }
          this.querySelector("svg #segments").prepend(p);
        })
      });
    }

    pathToArray(path) {
      if (typeof path != "string") path = path.getAttribute("d");
      const PATH_COMMANDS = {
        M: ["x", "y"],
        m: ["dx", "dy"],
        H: ["x"],
        h: ["dx"],
        V: ["y"],
        v: ["dy"],
        L: ["x", "y"],
        l: ["dx", "dy"],
        Z: [],
        C: ["x1", "y1", "x2", "y2", "x", "y"],
        c: ["dx1", "dy1", "dx2", "dy2", "dx", "dy"],
        S: ["x2", "y2", "x", "y"],
        s: ["dx2", "dy2", "dx", "dy"],
        Q: ["x1", "y1", "x", "y"],
        q: ["dx1", "dy1", "dx", "dy"],
        T: ["x", "y"],
        t: ["dx", "dy"],
        A: ["rx", "ry", "rotation", "large-arc", "sweep", "x", "y"],
        a: ["rx", "ry", "rotation", "large-arc", "sweep", "dx", "dy"]
      };
      const items = path.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '').
      replace(/-/g, ' -').
      replace(/(\d*\.)(\d+)(?=\.)/g, '$1$2 ').
      trim().
      split(/\s*,|\s+/);
      const segments = [];
      let currentCommand = '';
      let currentElement = {};
      while (items.length > 0) {
        let it = items.shift();
        if (PATH_COMMANDS.hasOwnProperty(it))
          currentCommand = it;
        else
          items.unshift(it);
        currentElement = {
          type: currentCommand
        };
        PATH_COMMANDS[currentCommand].forEach((prop) => {
          it = items.shift(); // TODO sanity check
          currentElement[prop] = it;
        });
        if (currentCommand === 'M') {
          currentCommand = 'L';
        } else if (currentCommand === 'm') {
          currentCommand = 'l';
        }
        segments.push(currentElement);
      }
      return segments
    }
  });
</script>
<style>
  body {
    font: 12px Arial
  }
  b{
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:darkgreen;
  }
  svg {
    width: 180px;
    background: pink;
  }
  svg #segments path{
    cursor:pointer;
  }

</style>
```